# Run php File from html button with Ajax and Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, function

I've got a php function that i would like to run from a Html button I've got. 
The php function is on a separate file than the Html button.

So I've managed to do this with:

```
<input type="submit" name="test" id="bt1" value="RUN" /><br/>
```

But that is not what i want to do. I want to call the php function with:

```
<button id="bt1" class="button button5">< Random </button>
```

as there are other actions coupled with the button that need to run at the same time.

Side note: My php function gets info from a json file.

I've got 3 files.

File 1 (AF.php) this is where the button is
File 2(Display.php) This is where my jquery/javascript/ajax scripts are
File 3(Names.php) This is where the php function is. I want to use button from File 1 to run php function from File 3.

So here is what I've tried so far:

File 1(AF.php)

```
 button id="bt1" class="button button5">< R30K</button>
```

File 2(Display.php)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#bt1").on("click", (function () {
                getName("Names.php");
            })
        });
  function getName(Names.php) {
        $.ajax({
            url:"Names.php" + Names.php,
            success:function (Names.php) {
                $("#res" + Names.php).html(result)
            }
        });
```

File 3(Names.php)

```
<?php

    function group1(){
        $jsondata = file_get_contents("Clients.json");
        $json = json_decode($jsondata, true);
        $output = '<ul>';
        foreach($json['Reps']as $reps){
            $output .='<h4>' .$reps['Client']."<h4>";
            $output .= "<li>".$reps['repCode']."</li>";
        }

        $element = $json['Reps'][array_rand($json['Reps'])];
        echo $element['Client'];
        echo " ";
        echo $element['repCode'];
    }

    if(array_key_exists('bt1',$_POST)){
        group1();
    }

    ?>
```

Desired outcome would be that I can run my function from File 3 with that Html buttom from File 1.

You're help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML with that button and your jQuery code must be in the same document that is loaded by your browser, either by putting them in the same file or using php include/require.

That jQuery code will not run because you put "Names.php" everywhere (Why?). Try this:

```
$( function(){
    $("#bt1").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Names.php',
            type: 'get',
            success: function(data) {
                $("#res").html(data);
            },
        });
    });
});
```

This will put the ajax response string into any element with `id="res"`.

Code was tested and works.

**Edit:**

I just noticed that you are using `$_POST` in your php script to check if the button was clicked, so you will have to modify the jQuery ajax function:

Change `type: 'get',` to `type: 'post',`

Add `data: 'bt1=1',` after `'type: 'post'`.